# PHP, Looping through mulitple arrays - some arrays only have 1 result

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am working with the Zillow API to return reviews for a list of Agents. I have a `foreach` loop that then pulls the list of reviews for each agent. The list is returned as JSON. I then run a `foreach` loop on the JSON results to display the reviews individually. Everything works great except, a specific agent only has 1 review and it is throwing a `foreach` error.

Here is a very simple example return:

If an agent has multiple reviews:

```
array(
    [0] => Array (
        [reviewer] => name,
        [reviewerLink] => link
    ),
    [1] => Array (
        [reviewer] => name,
        [reviewerLink => link
    )
)
```

If an agent only has one review:

```
array([reviewer] => name [reviewerLink] => link)
```

I have tried using `count()`, but on an array with only 1 review, it counts the total keys since there is no index.

I need a simple way to differentiate the arrays so I don't use a `foreach` loop on the agents with only 1 review.

Is there a way to force the array to have an index? Or another way to differentiate the arrays?

Comment: You can prevent the foreach error like this: `foreach((array) $array as $item)`

Comment: I still get the error: "Illegal string offset"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only one review, the key `reviewer` exists. So you can check it with the function `array_key_exists` if you have only one or more.

Try this code example:

```php
if (array_key_exists('reviewer', $array)) {
  // only one review
} else {
  // more reviews
  // do the foreach
}
```

Comment: Make sure that your code for processing the review is a function or you could end with 2 places where the review data is processed.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://www.zillow.com/howto/api/ReviewsAPI.htm), there is a `reviewCount` field as part of the result set, so check this before the `foreach` and convert it to an array if only 1 item...

```
if ( $json['reviewCount'] == 1 )  {
    $array = [$array];
}
```

or if your json is an object...

```
if ( $json->reviewCount == 1 )  {
    $array = [$array];
}
```

this will mean that all versions are an array of reviews for the foreach.

Comment: Didn't even think about that! This would also work!

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if it is a multidimensional array, use `count($agent, 1);`, it will recursively count the array.
So, if `count($agent, 1);` is less than 3, the $agent has one review.

```
$ag1 =[
  0 =>[
    'reviewer' => 'name',
    'reviewerLink' => 'link'
  ],
  1 =>[
    'reviewer' => 'name',
    'reviewerLink' => 'link'
  ]
];

$ag2 =[
  'reviewer' => 'name',
  'reviewerLink' => 'link'
];

echo count($ag1, 1);  // 6
echo count($ag2, 1);  // 2
```

Just check:

```
if (count($agent, 1) <3) {
  // only one review
} else {
  // more reviews
  // do the foreach
}
```